# Why are my images loaded again and again in a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating an app to display listings and each listing has an amount of x images to be displayed in a table cell.

To display the images, I have to create the `UIImageView` dynamically and load the images into the cell via a `for` loop (depending on the data received from a server call).

Now, I am able to add the images dynamically, but when I scroll the table view, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function runs again and the images are loaded again into the cell, hence creating more image views than the actual data.

I want to keep the image count constant in the cell and do not want to create more images in the cell as the table scrolls.

Here is the function code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"ClassCell";

    ClassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    long row = [indexPath row];

    for (int t = 0; t<individualSports.count; t++) {
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((250/10*count+10), 125, 20, 20)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cricket_unselected.png"]];
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ClassCell` could take care of this for you. If it is used for other purposes, just subclass it again;

```
@implementation ClassCell // or a new ClassCell subclass
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    // for loop..
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use a `BOOL`:

```
@interface ClassCell
@property BOOL hasImageViews;
@end
```

and then:

```
if (!cell.hasImageViews) {
  cell.hasImageViews = YES;
  // for loop..
}
```

---

**Side note**: I'm not really sure why you want to add the same picture that many times to a single cell, though; isn't it more likely that you want to use a checkbox of some kind? Also, you're iterating with `t`, but then applying the frame with `count`, meaning that all of your image views are overlapped on each other because they have the same frame within the `cell`.

Comment: thanks, the loop is good and i have removed the count variable . the images are different , just to simplify the above code, i have removed if-else conditions.

Comment: Although i am implementing the class method that you suggested, will get back in case of any issue

Comment: Thanks bro! The bool method works like a charm, So stupid of not to think if it earlier.

Comment: i spotted another bug, the cells that are in display, are shoeing correct data but when i scroll to load another cells, the no of images in shown are wrong.

Comment: If you need a different number of images depending on your cell data, you should change how you add the images to the cell. Your original question was unclear about your intentions.

Comment: I have posted the question for the simillar problem again . Please check it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249027/adding-images-programmatically-via-loop-in-table-cell-ios