# adding images programmatically via loop in table cell + iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I am creating an app to display listings and each listing has x number of images to be displayed in table cell.

To display the images, i have to create the UIImageView dynamically and load the images in the cell in a for loop {depending on the data received from a server call}.

Now, i am able to add the images dynamically but the number of images displayed in cell is not correct. I have checked the array value and count of loop but still not able to understand that why images are not loading properly.

PROBLEM : 
first 3-4 cell that are loaded as the view is loaded shows correct number of programmatically added image views. But when i scroll to bottom of the table, the correct number of images are not displayed in the cell and shows random number of images

here is the function code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"VenueCell";
VenueCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

long row = [indexPath row];

if (!cell.hasImageViews) {
    cell.hasImageViews = YES;
    NSArray *individualSports = [_venueSports[row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] ;

    NSLog(@"sports132431 = %@",individualSports);
    for (int t = 0; t<individualSports.count; t++) {
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((250/10*t+10), 125, 20, 20)];
        if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Cricket"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cricket_unselected.png"]];
        } else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Basketball"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"basketball_unselected.png"]];
        } else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Football"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"football_unselected.png"]];
        } else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Lawn Tennis"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lawn_unselected.png"]];
        } else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Squash"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squash_unselected.png"]];
        } else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Table Tennis"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_unselected.png"]];
        }  else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Badminton"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"badminton_unselected.png"]];
        }  else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Pool"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pool_unselected.png"]];
        }  else if ([individualSports[t] isEqual:@"Swimming"]) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swiming_unselected.png"]];
        }
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }
    individualSports = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"sports = %@",_venueSports[row]);
    NSLog(@"asx=%@",individualSports);
}


return cell;

}
```

// hasImageViews is a bool variable of VenueCell class

Any suggestion is good.
Thanks in advance!

**Update**: Here is the updated code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

long row = [indexPath row];
// Configure the cell...

long row = [indexPath row]; 
cell.vName.text = _venueName[row];
cell.vTiming.text = _venueTiming[row];
cell.vAreaName.text = _venueArea[row];
cell.starRatingImage.backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"starsbackground iOS.png"];
cell.starRatingImage.starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
cell.starRatingImage.starHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"starhighlighted.png"];
cell.starRatingImage.maxRating = 5.0;
cell.starRatingImage.delegate = self;
cell.starRatingImage.horizontalMargin = 12;
cell.starRatingImage.editable=NO;
cell.starRatingImage.rating=[_venueAvgRating[row] floatValue] ;
cell.starRatingImage.displayMode=EDStarRatingDisplayAccurate;




NSArray *individualSports = [_venueSports[row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] ;

for (int t = 0; t<individualSports.count; t++) {
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((25*t+10), 125, 20, 20)]; 

    // Since each of your individualSports[t] options
    // first words is simply the prefix to your image file name,
    // you can simplify the contents of your loop like so:
    NSString *firstWord = (NSString*)[[individualSports[t] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_unselected.png", firstWord.lowercaseString]]];

    [cell addSubview:imageView];
} 
if([_venueCategory[row] isEqualToString:@"Partner"]){ 

    cell.vImageCategory.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue_partner.png"];
} 
else if([_venueCategory[row] isEqualToString:@"Verified"]){
    cell.vImageCategory.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue_verified.png"];
} 
else{ 

    cell.vImageCategory.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"venue_unverified.png"];
}
cell.vImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"agon_logo.png"];



return cell;

}
```

Comment: Haven't really looked over your code, but this equation: 250/10*t+10 equals 25*t+10, so you could simplify it big time

Comment: And since you're reusing your cells, this comparison result `if (!cell.hasImageViews) {` probably isn't doing what you expect since you're reusing that property too. And also the fact that you're adding subviews while reusing cells is a big no-no in this case.

Comment: I dont think that you should use loop for assigning the images.You should store titlle of type of sports in an array.and use it in cell.textLabe.text=[sportsArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.Row];

Comment: I have to add images not the labels and the number so images is not known so i have to add the for loop

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott: i am bit of a newbie in ios development so could you please guide me to the correct solution to this issue

Comment: @Neelanshu I'll write up an explanation.

Comment: @LyndseyScott when tableview is loaded , data only for visible cells is loaded.and using for loop is very bad technique in this sceneario

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott : thanks! I am also looking up the issue on google

Comment: This actually sounds like a better candidate for a `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Logic You're misunderstanding the OP's data structure and the purpose of the loop. It's definitely necessary since the number of image view's in a cell is dynamic. There can be 1 image view in one cell and 7 in another, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, since you're reusing your cells, this comparison -- `if (!cell.hasImageViews) {` -- won't necessarily hold the appropriate value for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`'s current cell since the cell that's being reused can be different from the current cell. For example, if 4 cells of your table view can fit on your screen at once, when you scroll to cell 5 which was originally off the table, reusing it means that it contains the contents and property values of cell 1. So that comparison is completely irrelevant.

In this specific case though, it makes no sense whatsoever to reuse your cells since the entire contents of the cells are completely different for each row. Also, since your custom table view cell seems to only contain the `.hasImageViews` property, using a custom cell is unnecessary in this case since, as we've already established, we won't be reusing the cells.

Lastly, you can greatly simplify the conditionals within your for loop as I've done in my code below.

To implement these changes, I recommend doing something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    long row = [indexPath row];

    NSArray *individualSports = [_venueSports[row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] ;

    for (int t = 0; t<individualSports.count; t++) {
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((25*t+10), 125, 20, 20)];

        // Since each of your individualSports[t] options
        // first words is simply the prefix to your image file name,
        // you can simplify the contents of your loop like so:
        NSString *firstWord = (NSString*)[[individualSports[t] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_unselected.png", firstWord.lowercaseString]]];

        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

(Note: You've spelled "swimming" incorrectly in the file name so the change I made to your conditional won't work for that one if you don't edit the file name in your bundle.)

**Update:** As is now clear from your updated code, `VenueCell` had other properties beyond the ones apparent in your original question, so perhaps it makes sense to reuse your cells after all. To do that though, you'll have to clear out your old `UIImageView` subviews during each call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, ex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"VenueCell";
    VenueCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.vName.text = _venueName[row];
    cell.vTiming.text = _venueTiming[row];
    cell.vAreaName.text = _venueArea[row];
    cell.starRatingImage.backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"starsbackground iOS.png"];
    // ... all the other starRatingImageCode ...
    cell.starRatingImage.displayMode=EDStarRatingDisplayAccurate;

    // Clear out any images previously added to the
    // cell during cellForRowAtIndexPath (images have been
    // assigned a tag of 1000 in the next for loop)
    for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
        if (subview.tag == 1000) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    NSArray *individualSports = [_venueSports[row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] ;

    for (int t = 0; t<individualSports.count; t++) {
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((25*t+10), 125, 20, 20)];
        imageView.tag = 1000 //<-- Use a tag unique to these image views

        NSString *firstWord = (NSString*)[[individualSports[t] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_unselected.png", firstWord.lowercaseString]]];

        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }

    // Assuming the only "else" condition is "default",
    // I've similarly simplified this code as I did with
    // your other conditional
    cell.vImageCategory.image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"venue_%@.png", _venueCategory[row].lowercaseString];
    cell.vImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"agon_logo.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i am applying the solution you mentioned

Comment: @Neelanshu And though the loop is necessary,  I'll update my answer to simplify your implementation greatly...one sec...

Comment: Thanks ! applying this

Comment: @Neelanshu Also note that lawn tennis is two words, when the file name is just lawn... I'm actually going to make one last edit to my code to handle that situation too... one sec...

Comment: thanks ! it works like a charm. The issue is solved i just need to configure the cell to show rest of the things and will be done with it

Comment: @Neelanshu Great :) But also make sure to note the edit I just made to that line in the for loop, because it will allow your code to also work for "lawn tennis" by only using the first word of every string. And remember to change "swiming _unselected" to "swimming_unselected" in your bundle.

Comment: Thanks! i have seen that

Comment: @Lyndsey :but here re using the cell is not happening . can you clear me?

Comment: @sanginadhammurali As I explain in my answer: "In this specific case though, it makes no sense whatsoever to reuse your cells ... since the entire contents of the cells are completely different for each row."

Comment: you mean if the content (i.e if the number of images for each cell) is different then we can not re use according to requierment.is'n t it?

Comment: @sanginadhammurali You can reuse the cell, but what's the point of doing that if you're just going to remove the old reused contents each time anyway in order to populate a row with completely new content... It doesn't make sense to do that...

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott : the image issue is solved but I am facing another issue that the rest of the data is not populating as the outlets to the labels are in my VenueCell class but if i move them to my current class.h file, the data is not populating in the table cell other than dynamic images of the sports. also the segue is not performed .

Comment: Could you please look into it as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Neelanshu I formulated my answer around the code in your original question, so I didn't realize your VenueCell contained other properties... You may want to reuse your cells in that case, but as Tyler Mecham suggested, you'd have to clear out the images...I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: @Neelanshu Updated. (And P.S. never completely change the code in your original question after receiving answers because then those answers will no longer make sense. If necessary, add the new code underneath the old as an update.)

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott: Thanks! a lot. I ll keep in minD not to change the code so much

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott : HEY! can you please look into this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340840/conflict-in-return-type-of-the-function-ios

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reusing cells, you need to clear out the images that were previously added to the cell before you start adding the new images to it.  If you don't have a lot of cells to display, you may not want to reuse the cells at all.

Comment: :the number of cells is dynamic and hence can not be controlled by me. Could you be please more clear about the reuse identifier thing as I am a newbie in iOS development.

Comment: Basically when you reuse cells, you have a cache of this visible cells.  As soon as a cell scroll off the top of the screen, the exact same cell shows up at the bottom.  If you don't clean up the cell, you will see the same info that just scrolled off the top since it is the same cell being reused.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to download them backgroundly on seperate thread (don't write this code on cellForAtIndexPath(it may be in viewdidload))and upon successful dowload you have to reload the tableview. just take one custom cell with only one imageview.

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
       UIImage *image;
        NSMutableArray *imageArray;

        for (int i=0; i<[totalImgesURLSArray count]; i++) {
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[totalImgesURLSArrayobjectAtIndex:i]]];
            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

            [imageArray addObject:image];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [tableview reloadData];

        });
    });

}

       - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {

        return [imageArray count];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

for Example an Array

```
NSArray *sportsTypeArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cricket",@"Football",@"Hockey",@"Skitting",@"Running", nil];
```

inCellForRowAtIndex method

```
cell.textLabel.text=[sportsArray objectAtindex=indexPath.row];

if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Cricket"]
{

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cricket.png"];
}

else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Football"]
{

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"footBall.png"];
}
```

etc.  using loop is not good idea.Try this and tell if any problem.

Comment: I disagree. Using a loop is necessary in this case since the OP doesn't know the number of images required per row.

Comment: from where NSArray *individualSports gettig data? from server?

Comment: @Logic : Yea the array is fetched from the server

Comment: Can you show the  data stored in array?  actually.. tableview should be loaded when data from the server is already loaded.then you do not need to use loop at all