# conflict in return type of the function + IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking-2, http-method

I'm building an iOS app and i'm using AFNetworking library to POST data to the server.

I have created a function to post data and calling this function in different classes in my app.

I am getting response of the request in the variable called  "responseObject" , And i want to return this in the return statement i am not able to identify the return type of  responseObject and hence of the function,I tried using NSDictionary but getting following warning:

```
Conflicting return type in implementation of 'postData:parameters:': 'void' vs 'NSDictionary *'
```

here is my code:

```
-(void)postData:(NSString*)postUrl parameters:(NSDictionary *)params{


    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz:2424/api/"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:postUrl parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)

     {

         NSLog(@"response   %@",responseObject);

     }
                failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"\n============== ERROR ====\n%@",error);

              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error adding book" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alertView show];


          }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First u can see the class type of the responseObject by typing NSLog(@"ClassType-%@",[responseObject class]).Then by custom delegate pass the responseObject to the desired type.

Comment: i am getting the class as __NSCFDictionary but this is what i can not return in the function return type, Could you please suggest some thing

Comment: Please show your method in which u want to return this dictionary.Because in the code u didn;t showing anything working after nslog.

Comment: I don't want void return type of method ,i want return type as responseObject.And responseObject has class __NSCFDictionary

Comment: Ok but with this you can't return dictionary as it is block function.So for this u can use CUSTOM DELEGATE or NSNOTIFICATIONDEFAULTCENTER.

Answer (score 0):

This means your postData method is expecting an NSDictionary to be returned, however your method says "void" - have a look at the method definition in your header file , I expect it is:

```
-(NSDictionary*)postData:(NSString*)postUrl parameters:(NSDictionary *)params;
```